# Headers imported inside Bridging Header are not visible in 'Release' build configuration but visible in 'Debug' build configration

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I have created an Objective-C bridging header in my Swift project and added an import statement inside my bridging header to import an Objective-C class. When I compile the project using 'Debug' build configuration, my Swift classes are able to see this Objective-C class. But when I compile the project using 'Release' build configuration, my Swift classes are not able to see this Objective-C class, which is totally weird. My Build Settings are nearly the same for 'Debug' and 'Release', especially for 'header search paths' and 'framework search paths'. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check `Objective-C Bridging Header` in Target settings. Possibly you set it up for Debug only, but not for Release configuration.
Here is the reference to related [Swift docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for pointing this to me. The problem is that I had an extra setting for 'Any Architecture | Any SDK' as a child of the 'Release' configuration, and the value for this setting was empty, then the bridging header was not found when I chose 'Release' configuration.